# Can't configure Unirest request body

Tags: java, php, api, httprequest, unirest

Making service for connecting with QwintryLogistics API (http://logistics.qwintry.com), coding on Java + Unirest library, but all docs for API is in PHP, so structure of request body is unclear for me.
Part of documentation about POST request:

```
<?php
    define('SITE_URL', 'logistics.qwintry.com');
    define('API_KEY', 'YOUR_API_KEY'); //don't forget to set your key!
    $url =  'http://'. SITE_URL .'/api/cost';
    $data = array ( 
        'params' => array(
            'weight' => 5, // in lb
            'delivery_pickup' => 'msk_1', // full list of pickup points can be retrieved from /api/locations-list
            'insurance' => true,
            'items_value' => 500, // declaration items total cost in USD
            'retail_pricing' => true // retail / wholesale pricing?
        ),
     );
    $data_string = http_build_query($data);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '. API_KEY));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    var_dump($response);
```

So I need help to configure my Unirest POST request.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Made it like that:

```
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("params[weight_kg]", weight);
    params.put("params[dimensions_cm]", dimensions);
    params.put("params[delivery_pickup]", toPickup);
    params.put("params[insurance]", insurance);
    params.put("params[items_value]", value);
    params.put("params[retail_pricing]", RETAIL_PRICING);

    String url = BASE_URL+"/api/cost";
    HttpResponse<JsonNode> jsonResponse = Unirest.post(url).fields(params).asJson();
```

Works perfect :)